# Youtube Api URL not working

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

why this url not working

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=prdOEX1swb8&key=AIzaSyBmmnffjM5mosxIBIuemIeuW8wMwiAbrU2%20&part=snippet,statistics&fields=items(id,snippet,statistics)

I try take video data like {likes,title,category,date,etc...}

I want create application android

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to the message returned, your key is invalid. Works fine with my key. Check your [Google API key](https://console.developers.google.com/) . Did you set any restrictions?

Comment: yes I changed url to https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=AIzaSyBf6Wj7FsYB-tMM6z24yqeNYPIFq70xZU0&part=snippet,statistics

Comment: but tell me The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint. Please ensure that the client is sending them or use the API Console to update your key restrictions.

Comment: I hope help me :)